# Python curio and Callback

Tags: python, callback, async-await

I was getting my feet wet with the new async/await syntax in Python, by using the **curio** library.

The overall concept is fairly easy to grok, but now I've stumpled upon a case, where I need to transfer the result, which I receive via a **callback function, into the asynchronous environment**.

In the project I use the **scapy** library to capture network packets, which I want to receive and process in real time. That's why I am stuck with the callback and can't expect a async variant of the functionaity.

In my current approach I try to handle this via curios own queues. But since I am calling an async operation in the synchonous environment, I wrapped the put-function of the queue in in curio.run(queue.put(data)). Data is being trasmitted to the receiver as intended, but only after ther thread has finished.

The code for capturing the packets looks like this:

```
from scapy.all import sniff
from functools import partial


def async_receiver_wrapper(queue, pkt):
    # curio.run(queue.put(pkt))
    try:
         print("callback: " + pkt.summary())
         queue.put(pkt).send(None)
    except StopIteration:
         pass


async def capture(pkt_queue, ev, timeout=None, count=0):
        on_rx = partial(receiver, pkt_queue, ev)

        sniff(iface="eth0", prn=on_rx, timeout=timeout, count=count, store=0)
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
import curio
import sniffer
# import queue

async def start(self, intercomp_queue, start_evt):
        pkt_queue = curio.Queue()
        # pkt_queue = queue.Queue()
        await sniffer.capture(pkt_queue, 10)  # queue and timeout

        while True:
            pkt = await pkt_queue.get()
            print("Received: " + pkt.summary())
            await pkt_queue.task_done()

            # alternative using queue.Queue instead of curio.Queue
            #pkt = await curio.abide(pkt_queue.get)
            #print("Received: " + pkt.summary())
            #await self.process_packet(pkt)
            #await curio.abide(pkt_queue.task_done)
```

The resulting ouput of this code is:

```
Callback: Ether / ARP who has 10.0.0.15 says 10.0.0.1
Callback: Ether / ARP is at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx says 10.0.0.15
Callback: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Callback: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Callback: Ether / IP / TCP ... FPA / Raw
...
Received: Ether / ARP who has 10.0.0.15 says 10.0.0.1
Received: Ether / ARP is at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx says 10.0.0.15
Received: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Received: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Received: Ether / IP / TCP ... FPA / Raw
...
```

But I'd like it to be

```
Callback: Ether / ARP who has 10.0.0.15 says 10.0.0.1
Received: Ether / ARP who has 10.0.0.15 says 10.0.0.1
Callback: Ether / ARP is at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx says 10.0.0.15
Received: Ether / ARP is at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx says 10.0.0.15
Callback: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Received: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Callback: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Received: Ether / IP / TCP ... PA / Raw
Callback: Ether / IP / TCP ... FPA / Raw
Received: Ether / IP / TCP ... FPA / Raw
...
```

As it can be seen in the snippet, I've already tried using the original queues, which is supposed to work for synchronizing between another thread and the async. task.